# Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mEmail не работает

Tags: java, android, email

При формировании письма, не заполняется поле получателя.

```
public void sendMessage() {
        try {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mEmail);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mTitle);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMessage);
            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, mTitle));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String mMessage = textMessage.getText().toString();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"example@mail"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mTitle);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMessage);
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, mTitle));
```